# Problems passing a 2D array to a method using bracket notation in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a struct that holds some information about an animation, I want to be able to initialize the struct with a 2D array, without creating and initializing the array first.

The constructor of my Animation struct is as follows:

```
Animation( int frames[][2], int count );
```

I want to achieve something like this:

```
Animation* m_PlayerAnimation = new Animation( { { 3, 9 }, { 11, 9 }, { 19, 9 } }, 3 );
```

I know it's possible as follows, however I'm looking for a 1-line solution:

```
int arr[][2] = { { 3, 9 }, { 11, 9 }, { 19, 9 } };
Animation* m_PlayerAnimation = new Animation( arr, 3 );
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `std::array` instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is where you have the argument `int frames[][2]`, `frames` is a pointer. So you can't create something in-place there, since it won't be a pointer. This is a holdover from C.

If you want to be able to in-place create an arbitrary array, you'll have to change your constructor to:

```
template <size_t N>
Animation(const int (&frames)[N][2]) { .. }
```

which lets you write:

```
Animation a({{0,1}});
```

At this point the `count` argument becomes redundant, as it's replaced by the template parameter `N`.

Alternatively, you could just use `vector`:

```
Animation(std::vector<std::array<int, 2>> const& v) { .. }
```

which can be used the same way:

```
Animation a({{0, 1}});
```

Comment: I think the latter approach is preferable because it avoids the redundant `count` argument (`count == v.size()`). Also, it avoids adding a template which can mean moving the constructor definition into a header file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm going to use the latter aproach since there is no performance gain in using my own memory management if I have to use a template, which actually does simplify a lot of other code aswell :P